# Is this the most searched for tag on the site?

Tags: discussion

See a screenshot of what a search of "mi yodeya" yields.

This search was done in Incognito mode.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting find!

I suspect that the story is something like this:

If you search twitter.com for [all posts containing "judaism.stackexchange.com"](https://twitter.com/search?q=%22judaism.stackexchange.com%22&src=typed_query&f=live), you'll find that multiple times a week, people tweet links to Mi Yodeya posts for the purpose of debunking antisemitic memes. I presume this is true because twitter.com's population includes many 1) antisemites and 2) people who like to post links to debunk other tweets. (This behavior could be prevalent on other social media platforms as well.) In particular, most of these links are to [Does the talmud promote pedophilia?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65726/does-the-talmud-promote-pedophilia). This post is tagged [sexuality](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexuality) as are some other posts in the same genre. So, when Google crawls the internet and catalogues links to our site, it finds many, many to that post in particular, so it determines that category links related to that post are likely to be interesting to searchers.